# Parse error. Expecting '}', ',', got 'EOF'

Tags: json, parsing, error-handling

I'm looking for errors in a data file because it's making a game to get stucked and not start. I'm absolutely ignorant in programming, so don't kill me if this is senseless.
The error (JSONLint):

Error: Parse error on line 6782:
...cSpeciesCached": 0.0
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', got 'EOF'

The last part of the file:

```
"facilities": [{
  "cityID": "Qk3s7KAzLwUz7v0KQjUdCZyW0X2x9rZc",
  "constructionType": 0,
  "constructionTimer": {
    "repeatMax": 7200,
    "timeInterval": 4680,
    "hasFired": true,
    "repeats": false,
    "shouldCatchUp": true,
    "shouldStop": true,
    "iterationThreshold": 2340,
     "iterations": 19849
    },
    "upgradeTimer": {
      "repeatMax": 7200,
      "timeInterval": 3600,
      "hasFired": true,
      "repeats": false,
      "shouldCatchUp": true,
      "shouldStop": true,
      "iterationThreshold": 1800,
      "iterations": 3606
    },
    "facilityID": "HA17AvUZYVNrGIW64FrOOzx5eIXyX2vG",
    "type": 33,
    "level": 2,
    "isDisabled": false,
    "isOnMoon": true,
    "heatCached": 0.0,
    "airPressureCached": 0.0,
    "oxygenContentCached": 0.0,
    "seaLevelCached": 0.0,
    "biomassCached": 0.0,
    "aquaticSpeciesCached": 0.0
```

The whole file is 6782 lines long, I think this is too big for finding an error, is it?

Comment: Is this the end of the file? looks truncated to me (it's missing at least two closing brackets, "}" and "]"

Comment: Yes it should end right there, that could be the problem (I dont know). How would you do it?

Comment: This is the saved data file. Maybe because of it has to grow with new data?

Comment: Your `JSON` is invalid - you are missing closing `}` & `]`

Comment: could you write how to close it? I am ignorant of this. 
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'     because I surely am writing it bad